# linq to entities dynamic where clause as string

Tags: c#, linq-to-entities

I want to filter data dynamically using linq to entities, by providing string expression to where clause.

For example:

```
string filterExpr = "it.City='London'"
var ret1 = Contex.Customers.Where(filterExpr);
```

How can I do the same but this time to filter data that **starts with** some string?

if it's not possible to achieve using string, how can I build a appropriate Lambda expression?

(Also it's important to me to be able to filter by many parameters (OR/AND) )

Answer (score 2):

I think what you might be looking for is Dynamic LINQ.  Scott Guthrie posted this:

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx

It's not as fast as using the lambda syntax since they need to be compiled at run-time, but it might be your answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
Public Shared Function getFilterStartsWith(Of T)(ByVal param As ParameterExpression, ByVal prop As MemberExpression, ByVal arg As Object) As Expression
    Dim mi As MethodInfo = GetType(String).GetMethod("StartsWith", New Type() {GetType(String)}, Nothing)
    Return Expression.Lambda(Of Func(Of T, Boolean))(LambdaExpression.[Call](prop, mi, Expression.Constant(arg, GetType(String))), param)
End Function
```

In C#:

```
public static Expression getFilterStartsWith<T>(ParameterExpression param, MemberExpression prop, object arg) {
    MethodInfo mi = typeof(string).GetMethod("StartsWith", new Type[] { typeof(string) }, null);
    return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(LambdaExpression.Call(prop, mi, Expression.Constant(arg, typeof(string))), param);
}
```

That's the function I'm using for startsWith in a [solution](http://snipt.org/xLkp) I recently wrote.  It turned out to be a huge pain because you can't use a Type variable as a parameter in ctype or DirectCast in vb and you can't do linq comparisons on a an object and a nullable object of the same type.

Comment: Damn, VB is even more verbose than I thought.

Comment: c# syntax please if it's not hard

Answer (score 0):

please try this:

```
var ret1 = contex.Customers.Where(x => x.it.City.StartsWith('l'));
```

HTH

Comment: lambda expressions for the win!

Comment: but I've explained that I can't use it! Where doesn't know about "x.it.City" cause it gets the property to fillter by on runtime

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question of how to specify the filter dynamically in a string

Comment: OOPs...my bad...could you try this: tring filterExpr = "it.City like 'L%'". HTH

Answer (score 0):

Forget about "magic" strings, C# is meant to be strongly typed.
One way or another You end up with a list of where's so the best way is to have them strongly typed.

```
    public class Veg
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public bool Fruit { get; set; }
    }

    enum Mode
    {
        One,
        Two,
        Three
    }

    static void Main()
    {
        Mode mode = Mode.One;

        var data = new List<Veg>
        {
            new Veg{Id = 1, Name = "Apple", Fruit = true},
            new Veg{Id = 2, Name = "Carrot", Fruit = false}
        };

        var dataSelect = data.Where(w => (mode == Mode.One && w.Fruit) || //only fruits
                                         (mode == Mode.Two && !w.Fruit) || //only not fruits
                                         (mode == Mode.Three)); //all of it
    }
```